# Standard for modelling JSON data in IOS

Tags: ios, json

I have some JSON data I'm pulling into an IOS app. Now coming from a .Net background I would normally create a 'Model' for the data like so.

```
public class MyData{
    public IEnumerable<SubData> ActualData {get;set;}
    public string SomeValue {get;set;
}

public class SubData {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now using, ObjectiveC - whats the recommended method? I've seen lots of uses Dictionary style objects and not yet seen an example of actual class based models. I'm fully aware I could use the model based approach but I don't want to 'go against the grain', I'm using NSJSONSerialization to parse the JSON if that makes a difference.

I've done some mapping to simple JSON objects using

```
[result objectForKey:@"Key"];
```

But now I need to deal with more complex JSON (With X number of elements) data the strings no longer seem to cut it.

Comment: Lots of people will use `NSDictionary` objects (particularly for superficial examples you'll see here on S.O.), but many of us will tend to use meaningfully named model objects (e.g. a `Person` object with `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. properties rather than just some `NSDictionary`-based structure). It's not "against the grain" at all to use proper model objects.

Comment: If you're looking for examples, perhaps you can modify your question to use a less abstract example. Pick some simple concrete example, show us what the JSON might look like and what the class should look like, and we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I think you've answered my question, I'll roll out a model based pattern and see how I get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather opinion based, but I guess most people use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` if the storage is just temporary. If the storage is longer term then you might move the data into core data, which is easy to do with KVC from the dictionary and array structure, or using a library like RestKit. A similar approach can be used for custom `NSObject` subclasses.

I think the important thing is to be clear about what you're doing and to make the implementation clear (or well documented).